Linked Chart with chart.js@4.4.2 and crosshair@2.0.0
Does Linked Chart with chart.js@4.4.2 and crosshair@2.0.0 work?
Below is the code I'm trying.

Issue: no crosshair and tooltip in the other chart

When hovering over a dot the corresponding dot in the other chart is getting smaller.
I have derived my example from https://chartjs-plugin-crosshair.netlify.app/samples/
Any help would be very much appreciated.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>LinkedChartNEW.html</title>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.4.2/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-crosshair@2.0.0"></script>
</head>
<body>

<main style="width:90vw;">
  <div><canvas id="chart1"></canvas></div>
  <div><canvas id="chart2"></canvas></div>
</main>

<script>
Chart.Tooltip.positioners.cursor =  function(chartElements, coordinates) {
                                        return coordinates;
                                    };
var yMin = -10;
var yMax = +60;
function generateDataset(label, color) {
  var data = [];
  var x = 0;

  while (x <= 30) {
    data.push({ x: x, y: x });
    x++;
  }

  var dataset = {
    backgroundColor: color,
    borderColor: color,
    showLine: true,
    fill: false,
    pointRadius: 8,
    label: label,
    data: data,
  };
  return dataset;
}

const options = {
  plugins: {
    crosshair: {
      sync: {
        enabled: true,
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      position: 'cursor',
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false,
    }
  },
  scales: {
    x: {
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'bottom',
    },
    y: {
        min: yMin,
        max: yMax,
        ticks:{ stepSize: 5, }
    }
  },
};

var chart1 = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart1").getContext("2d"), {
  type: "scatter",
  options,
  data: {
    datasets: [
      generateDataset("A", "red"),
    ]
  }
});

var chart2 = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart2").getContext("2d"), {
  type: "scatter",
  options,
  data: {
    datasets: [
      generateDataset("B", "blue"),
    ]
  }
});

</script>
</body>
</html>

